# Pivot rows into columns with values of counts for each measurement R

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, plyr, reshape2

I have a sample dataframe that I am working with

```
ID <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
TARG_AVG <- c(2.1,2.1,2.1,2.1,2.1,2.1,2.3,2.3,2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.3,3.3,3.3,3.3,3.5,3.5)
Measurement <- c("Len","Len","Len","Wid","Ht","Ht","Dep","Brt","Ht","Ht","Dep","Dep"
                 ,"Dep","Dep","Len","Len","Ht","Ht","Brt","Brt","Wid","Wid")
df1 <- data.frame(ID,TARG_AVG,Measurement)
```

I am trying to solve 3 different problems here

1) I want to get the summary of how many unique measurements are there for (ID & TARG_AVG) grouping. I currently do this

```
unique <- summaryBy(Measurement~ID+TARG_AVG, data=df1, FUN=function(x) { c(Count=length(x)) } )
```

This gives me the total (measurement.count) but I want the counts for each measurements too. **My desired output** is

```
  ID TARG_AVG Len Wid Ht Dep Brt Measurement.Count
1  A      2.1   3   1  2   0   0                 6
2  A      2.3   0   0  0   1   1                 2
3  A      2.5   0   0  2   2   0                 4
4  B      3.1   2   0  0   2   0                 4
5  B      3.3   0   0  2   0   2                 4
6  B      3.5   0   2  0   0   0                 2
```

2) Once I get the above output, I would like to subset the rows so that I get a filtered output that returns rows that have at least a count of 2 measurements **> 2** . Here **my desired output** would be

```
  ID TARG_AVG Len Wid Ht Dep Brt Measurement.Count
1  A      2.1   3   1  2   0   0                 6
3  A      2.5   0   0  2   2   0                 4
4  B      3.1   2   0  0   2   0                 4
5  B      3.3   0   0  2   0   2                 4
```

3) Finally, I would like to pivot back the columns into rows with only measurements **> 2**. **My desired output** here would be

```
      ID TARG_AVG Measurement
    1  A      2.1   Len   
    2  A      2.1   Len   
    3  A      2.1   Len   
    4  A      2.1   Ht   
    5  A      2.1   Ht   
    6  A      2.5   Ht   
    7  A      2.5   Ht   
    8  A      2.5   Dep  
    9  A      2.5   Dep  
   10  B      3.1   Len  
   11  B      3.1   Len  
   12  B      3.1   Dep 
   13  B      3.1   Dep
   14  B      3.3   Ht 
   15  B      3.3   Ht 
   16  B      3.3   Brt 
   17  B      3.3   Brt
```

I am learning reshape2, dplyr & data.table packages at the moment and would be very useful if someone would help me solve this by pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Newest solution**

```
library(data.table) #v 1.9.6+
setDT(df1)[, indx := .N, by = names(df1)
           ][indx > 1, if(uniqueN(Measurement) > 1) .SD, by = .(ID, TARG_AVG)]
#     ID TARG_AVG Measurement indx
#  1:  A      2.1         Len    3
#  2:  A      2.1         Len    3
#  3:  A      2.1         Len    3
#  4:  A      2.1          Ht    2
#  5:  A      2.1          Ht    2
#  6:  A      2.5          Ht    2
#  7:  A      2.5          Ht    2
#  8:  A      2.5         Dep    2
#  9:  A      2.5         Dep    2
# 10:  B      3.1         Dep    2
# 11:  B      3.1         Dep    2
# 12:  B      3.1         Len    2
# 13:  B      3.1         Len    2
# 14:  B      3.3          Ht    2
# 15:  B      3.3          Ht    2
# 16:  B      3.3         Brt    2
# 17:  B      3.3         Brt    2
```

Or the `dplyr` equivalent

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(ID, TARG_AVG, Measurement) %>%
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  group_by(ID, TARG_AVG) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(Measurement) > 1)
```

---

**Older solution**

```
library(data.table)
## dcast the data (no need in total)
res <- dcast(df1, ID + TARG_AVG  ~ Measurement)
## filter by at least 2 incidents of at least length 2
res <- res[rowSums(res[-(1:2)] > 1) > 1,]
## melt the data back and filter again by at least 2 incidents
res <- melt(setDT(res), id = 1:2)[value > 1]
## Expand the data back
res[, .SD[rep(.I, value)]]
```

---

**The solution to the original question**

Here's a possible solution using `reshape2`

1st step

```
library(reshape2)
res <- dcast(df1, ID + TARG_AVG  ~ Measurement, margins = "Measurement")
```

2nd step

```
res <- res[res$"(all)" > 2,]
```

3d step

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, if(.N > 2) .SD, by = .(ID, TARG_AVG)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but one thing I wanted to point out is that I really am not filtering the Total by (>2). I really want to filter the dataset based on measurements (I.e: Only if 2 of those measurements are above 2, I want to include the row. For example if the total is 5 and the combination of measurements is 3+1+1, then I dont want to include the row since only one measurement is above 2. Could you please check that?

Comment: My above df1 example might not be the best here since the filter can be applied to total itself rather than measurements. I am sorry for providing such an example.

Comment: @Sharath I had `which(res[, c(3:7)] >= 2, arr.ind = TRUE) -> ind; res[unique(ind[,1]),] %>% arrange(ID, TARG_AVG) ` for the 2nd part. I wonder if this is what you meant.

Comment: If you only need the last output why do you need all these steps before, you can reach it directly like in the other answer

Comment: jazzuro, thanks for the post but the prob is it is not filtering based on 2 measurements. I need a filter that returns rows with atleast 2 measurements that are >= 2.

Comment: See my edit regarding the third step, does this wok for you? You can change it to >= 2 in your real data set

Comment: @David, Yes you are right but the problem is that it is filtering based on total I believe because I see the 4th row (Wid) appearing in your solution. this is what I said earlier that I want to filter only based on measurements that are more than 2 which is what I am not knowing how to do. The total rows should be 17 and not 18. Could you please check that?. Please let me know if I am not clear.

Comment: David - Such a fantastic solution. This was so easy to understand. It works like charm. I am going to apply to a bigger dataset that I have and get back to you.

Comment: I've added another solution, try it too.

Comment: Wow David. It worked beautifully on my large dataset and was super fast too. This is some amazing stuff. Thank you so much for being patient and helping me out.

Comment: See new update, I've improved the solution a bit further but you'll need the newest `data.table` version from CRAN (v 1.9.6) in order to use `uniqueN`. Also added a `dplyr` equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `tidyr` in this case. You only need `dplyr`:

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(ID, TARG_AVG) %>% # Group by ID and TARG_AVG
  mutate(count=n()) %>%      # Count how many are there for each combination of ID and TARG_AVG
  filter(count > 2) %>%      # Only keep the ones with more than 2 (I think you meant > 2)
  select(-count)             # Remove the auxiliary variable count
df2
```

A shorter (though less easily understandable) version is:

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(ID, TARG_AVG) %>%
  filter(n() > 2)
df2
```

In this case I used the `n()` function directly instead of generating the auxiliary `count` variable.

**EDIT:** If you really want all three steps with `dplyr` and `tidyr`, you can do:

```
ID <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
TARG_AVG <- c(2.1,2.1,2.1,2.1,2.1,2.1,2.3,2.3,2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.3,3.3,3.3,3.3,3.5,3.5)
Measurement <- c("Len","Len","Len","Wid","Ht","Ht","Dep","Brt","Ht","Ht","Dep","Dep"
                 ,"Dep","Dep","Len","Len","Ht","Ht","Brt","Brt","Wid","Wid")
df0 <- data.frame(ID,TARG_AVG,Measurement)
```

Steps 1 & 2. Summarise, count, filter by number of measurements and spread

```
df1 <- df0 %>%
  group_by(ID, TARG_AVG, Measurement) %>%
  summarise(count=n()) %>%
  group_by(ID, TARG_AVG) %>% # Step "2"
  filter(n() >= 2) %>%       # Step "2"
  spread(Measurement, count, fill = 0) %>% # Resume step "1"
  mutate(Measurement.count = Len + Wid + Ht + Dep + Brt)
df1
```

Step 3. Reshape again

```
df3 <- df2 %>%
  select(-Measurement.count) %>%
  gather(Measurement, dummy, Brt:Wid) %>%
  select(-dummy)
df3
```

Comment: This solves the third problem directly. If you want the intermediate steps then you'll have to stick to what you have or replicate it with `dplyr` and `tidyr` ^^

Comment: But someone already did it u.u If you _really_ want a version using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, I can post it. `reshape` and `reshape2` are the past!

Comment: Felipe. Could you post a solution for dplyr and tidyr? and please make sure you are applying filters based on measurements and not total. I want the filter to return rows that has atleast 2 measurements >= 2 and not the total >2. Please check that.

Comment: I would then recommend doing the filter in step 1. The thing is that you would have to write explicitly which variables you want to check for measurements, as opposed to simply grouping in a different manner.

Comment: Felipe - This works great with dplyr too. I will apply your solution to a bigger dataset and will let you know how that goes.

Comment: :) just be sure to use the last update (the one with the 2 group_by statements), because that is the one that filters by number of variables with a measurement as opposed to the total.

Comment: Felipe - I tried your solution on the bigger data set too after I ran david's script and I loved it :-) dplyr has some awesome functionality and I am hooked to it. Thanks for being patient and helping me out.

Comment: My pleasure! Hadleys new packages are intensely fast, aren't they? ^^

Answer (score 1):

Here's a data.table solution that may be a bit faster. I've found that subsetting in j with a by can be a bit slow compared to separating the task out into two steps: [1] Add extra columns you can use to filter on (do the by here), [2] perform the filter in one shot (without a by):

```
> cTbl[, N := .N, .(ID, TARG_AVG, Measurement)
      ][N > 1, NMgt1 := uniqueN(Measurement) > 1, .(ID, TARG_AVG)
      ][N > 1 & NMgt1
      ][, c('N', 'NMgt1') := NULL
      ][]



    ID TARG_AVG Measurement
 1:  A      2.1         Len
 2:  A      2.1         Len
 3:  A      2.1         Len
 4:  A      2.1          Ht
 5:  A      2.1          Ht
 6:  A      2.5          Ht
 7:  A      2.5          Ht
 8:  A      2.5         Dep
 9:  A      2.5         Dep
10:  B      3.1         Dep
11:  B      3.1         Dep
12:  B      3.1         Len
13:  B      3.1         Len
14:  B      3.3          Ht
15:  B      3.3          Ht
16:  B      3.3         Brt
17:  B      3.3         Brt
>
```